# Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null"

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I am using `echarts` to draw a `Heatmap`

But giving me error!!

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null"

```
mounted() {
  this.initChart()
},
```

I am using the json data from here: 
https://www.echartsjs.com/data/asset/data/hangzhou-tracks.json

Just took 1 data from the above link.

```
<template>
  <div
    :id="id"
    :class="className"
    :style="{height:height,width:width}"
  />
</template>

<script>
import echarts from 'echarts'
import resize from '../mixins/resize'

export default {
  mixins: [resize],
  props: {
    className: {
      type: String,
      default: 'chart'
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: 'newCustomerForecastChart'
    },
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: '200px'
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      default: '200px'
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null,
      dataArr: [
        {
            "coord":
            [
                120.14322240845,
                30.236064370321
            ],
            "elevation": 21
        },
        {
            "coord":
            [
                120.14280555506,
                30.23633761213
            ],
            "elevation": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {   
     this.initChart()
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (!this.chart) {
      return
    }
    this.chart.dispose()
    this.chart = null
  },
  methods: {
    initChart() {
      var points = [
          {
            "coord":
            [
                120.14322240845,
                30.236064370321
            ],
            "elevation": 21
        },
        {
            "coord":
            [
                120.14280555506,
                30.23633761213
            ],
            "elevation": 5
        }
      ]
      this.chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(this.id))
      var colors = ['#5793f3', '#d14a61', '#675bba'];

      this.chart.setOption({
        animation: false,
        bmap: {
            center: [120.13066322374, 30.240018034923],
            zoom: 14,
            roam: true
        },
        visualMap: {
            show: false,
            top: 'top',
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            seriesIndex: 0,
            calculable: true,
            inRange: {
                color: ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'heatmap',
            coordinateSystem: 'bmap',
            data: points,
            pointSize: 5,
            blurSize: 6
        }]
    });

    var bmap = myChart.getModel().getComponent('bmap').getBMap();
    bmap.addControl(new BMap.MapTypeControl());
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What is the problem actually?

Comment: please share a [mcve] of your code not an example from the software library

Comment: Can you edit it please?

Comment: I can but I don't have your code.

Comment: I have added the full code.

Comment: in the doc, the data array consists of arrays.
can you try data: [points]? 
otherwise the error is to general to find out what's happening whithout reproduceable example

Comment: The code doesn't contain `.type` that could give this error. There's not enough data. Please, read what https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is. The problem should be reproducible. It currently isn't. It's unknown how the component is used. It's unknown what line causes the error. The error has call stack and it's available only on your side. You can debug what line throws this error. Otherwise, please provide workable demo that can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

should use

> import * as echarts from 'echarts'

imstead of

> import echarts from 'echarts'